# ASP.NET ListView with DataPager throwing error after going to next page

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I have a problem in ListView with DataPager.

I have SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ADSConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_posts_getall" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and it was binded in ListView. I set my PageSize in DataPager to 5, so after navigating to next page.

It thrown an error

```
Procedure or function usp_posts_getall has too many arguments specified
```

in my **usp_posts_getall**, I only have 1 parameter

```
@thisCategoryID int
```

**What went wrong?**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function usp_posts_getall has too many arguments specified.]
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1951450
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849003
>    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
>    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
>    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>    System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
>    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +130
>    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
>    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
>    System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +57
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

Answer (score 1):

ok sorry,

I forgot to clear the SelectParameters because in my Page_Load, I have this code:

```
        Parameter param = new Parameter();
        param.Name = "thisCategoryID";
        param.Type = TypeCode.Int32;
        param.DefaultValue = SelectedCategoryID.ToString();

        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();  // <<--- and I forgot this
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(param);
```

it's working now